# Getting *just* one char from stdin

Tags: c

I am using C and I am trying to write a small game. But I need to read the input whenever the player tabs on a key (say <kbd>s</kbd>), and the program does something, without pressing the <kbd>enter</kbd>.

I have seen many posts answering this, but they all use `getchar()` or `getch()` from curses or `conio.h` in Windows. But that's not what I want. The result can *definitely* done because of 2 examples:

1. `vim` when the user tabs on the <kbd>:</kbd>, it will immediately turns into the command mode to let you type in the commands.
2. the `read`command in bash, whose `-n${number_you_want}` parameter can limit the chars it reads without <kbd>enter</kbd>.

But I wonder how they can do this even I already have the source of the functions in the examples. I still can't figure out how they do this.
The source code of `vim`'s [`inchar()`](http://pastebin.com/gZw2kBB9) from `getchar.c` and the `read` command from bash source [`read.def`](http://pastebin.com/jg80bV3L).

Can anyone help me explain how they works? Thanks in advance.

Comment: But that answer post is using C++, and the `read` command and `vim` don't use the `conio.h` and the `getch()` function though I can give it a try.

Comment: And I am using Linux instead of Windows, so no such `conio.h`.